# What is a logging policy?

Tags: logging

I'm not being language specific, I just cannot find much about logging policies on the internet.

Comment: Google gives me 1.060.000.000 results when I search for "logging policy".

Comment: @Martin it gives me only 36.700.000 results. Google logs in which country I live, I guess. :)

Comment: Gave me a ton as well. Unfortunately they were all about lumbering practices in northwest Canada.

Comment: You can also google "Security logging policy" "audit logging policy", etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A logging policy states what types of activities your application should track.

For example, in a shopping cart, your logging policy may be to track  (incomplete list - just some items to give you an idea)

- all administrative actions
- All invalid login attempts
- potentially fraudulent transactions
- Account impersonations
- Failed login attempts
- password changes

Basically, your policy should state what types of actions need to be logged in order to trace potential fraud, inappropriate use, etc.

If you're in a shop that writes multiple applications, this becomes more important because it can become a development standard.  (A requirement that's applied all projects, so it does not need to be explicitly stated for individual ones) or it may be that different applications have different policies.  However, even if you go with the second option, your company should have guidelines to tell you how to choose in each case.

Logging policies are generally required documents for certain certification standards (such as PCI) and even if you're NOT subject to regulation/certification, it's still important to know what to track, as it bears on the ability to investigate fraud AND on privacy of your users/customers.